# How do I enable multiple files selection while picking file using UIDocumentPickerViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocumentpickervc

I'm trying to pick file from Files App using `UIDocumentPickerViewController` but I can't see `Select` button for multiple selection in picker. Why this is happening? am i doing anything wrong? Can anyone help?

Code snippet :

```
NSArray *arrContents = @[@"public.content",@"public.item",@"public.composite-content",@"public.data",@"public.database",@"public.calendar-event",@"public.message",@"public.presentation",@"public.contact",@"public.archive",@"public.disk-image",@"public.text",@"public.plain-text",@"public.utf8-plain-text",@"public.utf16-external-plain-​text",@"public.utf16-plain-text",@"com.apple.traditional-mac-​plain-text",@"public.rtf"];

UIDocumentPickerViewController *dvc = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController 
alloc]initWithDocumentTypes:arrContents inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
dvc.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:dvc animated:true completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `dvc.allowsMultipleSelection = true;` after initialising `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.

Comment: Yeh!! even I'm facing the same issue.